# who know how to put down the title of pie in ionic 2

Tags: chart.js, pie-chart, simplepie

I want to put the label under the pie.who know please tell me.thank you!     here the code.

```
      this.pieChart = new Chart(this.pieCanvas.nativeElement, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#ff0000",
                    "#0000ff",
                    "#ffff00",
                    "#008000",
                    "#800080",
                    "#ffa500"
                ]
            }]
        }

    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the *label / legend* 's position.

```
options: {
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
    }
}
```

The full *code* would be like this ...

```
this.pieChart = new Chart(this.pieCanvas.nativeElement, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                    "#ff0000",
                    "#0000ff",
                    "#ffff00",
                    "#008000",
                    "#800080",
                    "#ffa500"
                ]
            }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    }
});
```